# reading xml returns nothing

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, document

I have a xml file which i want to read and output its data my xml is like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<serverfiles>
    <file name="picture1.jpg"/>
    <file name="file1.txt"/>
    <folder name="subfolder">
        <file name="picture2.jpg"/>
        <file name="file2.txt"/>
        <folder name="anotherfolder">
            <file name="file3.txt"/>
        </folder>
    </folder>
    <folder name="anotherfolder"/>      
</serverfiles>
```

And want to output it as such:

```
picture1.jpg
file1.txt
subfolder\picture2.jpg
subfolder\file2.txt
subfolder\anotherfolder\file3.txt
```

I have tried this :

```
  string xml = new WebClient().DownloadString("");
 XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
 xdoc.LoadXml(xml);

 XmlElement element = xdoc.DocumentElement;

 XmlAttributeCollection attr_coll = element.Attributes;

 for(int i = 0; i < attr_coll.Count; i++)
 {
     string attr_name = attr_coll[i].Name;
 }
```

But in for loop count i don't get anything can someone please help me.

Comment: Are you indicating that you do not see any output?

Comment: This wont work, you have to loop throgh every node snd look for the attribute in each node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use X-path:

```
        foreach (XmlNode file in xdoc.SelectNodes("//file"))
        {
            string filename = file.Attributes["name"].Value;

            foreach (XmlNode folder in file.SelectNodes("./ancestor::folder"))
            {
                string foldername = folder.Attributes["name"].Value;
                filename = foldername + "\\" + filename;
            }
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(filename);
        }
```

This code example works with your xml.

Good luck with your quest.

Comment: what is //file? is it location to my xml?

Comment: "file" is the tagname of the interesting tags.  The x-path of a file-tag anywhere in the xml is "//file".  Please, google XPath for a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use recursion to get desired results. I think it will be easier using LINQ to XML:

**Recursive function**

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(XElement source, string currentPath = "")
{
    foreach (var file in source.Elements("file"))
    {
        yield return currentPath + (string)file.Attribute("name");
    }
    foreach (var folder in source.Elements("folder"))
    {
        foreach (var file in GetFiles(folder, currentPath + (string)folder.Attribute("name") + "/"))
            yield return file;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

(...)

var doc = XDocument.Load("Input.txt");
var files = GetFiles(doc.Root).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

This LINQ to XML should do it, no loop so maybe a bit more efficient

```
    XDocument document = XDocument.Load("c:\\tmp\\test.xml");
    var files = from i in document.Descendants("file")
                where i.Attribute("name") != null
                select new
                    {
                        Filename = (i.Parent != null && i.Parent.Name == "folder" ?
                                        (i.Parent.Parent != null && i.Parent.Parent.Name== "folder" ?
                                        i.Parent.Parent.Attribute("name").Value + @"\" + i.Parent.Attribute("name").Value + @"\" + i.Attribute("name").Value :
                                        i.Parent.Attribute("name").Value + @"\" + i.Attribute("name").Value):
                                        i.Attribute("name").Value)

                    };
```

Comment: Your query returns incorrect results. Does not return full folders path, only the last one + file name.

Comment: Didn't see the 2nd level down, pretty sure some thinking can solve that though, will edit my answer shortly. Downvote is maybe a little premature :)

Comment: I will remove my downvote when you're answer is fixed. For now just remember, that file can be much deeper then 2 levels of folders :)

Comment: Well, It now handles 2 levels better than recursion would, but I must admit with every level down you go, you lose readability. I love a challenge though so will ponder this one as I put the kids to bed

Comment: You can't write down every possible case like that, because number of levels may be really huge. Don't think that you can find anything better than recursive algorithm.

Comment: Yeah, I know it cant go on like that beyond the 2 levels, would be awful to read and probably would effect performance too. I will have a think though and possible come back to admit defeat in an hour or so ;)

Comment: Ok, if you need to go down 2 levels, this beats looping. I mis-interpreted the question and this way cannot go much further down the file tree without involving a loop. Otherwise it would just get crazy. I will take your -1 on the chin